# HTTP downloader using Beast

Tags: c++, asynchronous, http, c++14, boost

I have written a small HTTP downloader using

- [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)
- [Beast library](https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast/) (proposed to be included in Boost)
- [`network::uri`](https://github.com/reBass/uri) library for handling URIs

It's nowhere near completion but I would like to get some feedback from you guys. I wanted to use as much of async interface as I could.

The idea is that it gets a `std::vector<std::string>` with URLs to fetch and then it goes callback after callback to finally print the response data on screen.

This review's purpose is that I would like to e.g. add support for HTTPS and while doing that I would like to write unit tests mocking somehow (and preferably splitting this class) network (asio) dependencies.

**Downloader.hpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

#include <beast/core/streambuf.hpp>
#include <beast/http/string_body.hpp>

#include <network/uri/uri.hpp>

class Downloader {
public:
  Downloader(const std::vector<std::string> &urls);
  void go();

private:
  void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                    std::shared_ptr<beast::http::response<beast::http::string_body>> response,
                    std::shared_ptr<beast::streambuf>);

  void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, const network::uri &uri);

  void queue_read(const boost::system::error_code &ec);

  void resolve_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                       boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it,
                       const network::uri &uri);

  std::vector<network::uri> uris;

  boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket tcp_socket;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolv;
};
```

**Downloader.cpp**

```
#include "Downloader.hpp"

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

#include <beast/http/empty_body.hpp>
#include <beast/http/read.hpp>
#include <beast/http/write.hpp>

#include <network/uri/uri.hpp>

using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2 etc.
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

Downloader::Downloader(const std::vector<std::string> &urls) : tcp_socket(ioservice), resolv(ioservice) {
  std::transform(urls.begin(), urls.end(), std::back_inserter(uris), [this](const std::string &url) {
    std::error_code ec;
    network::uri u(url, ec);
    if(ec) {
      ioservice.post([=] {
        std::cout << "Error parsing URL : " << url << '\n' << "Error code : " << ec.message() << '\n';
      });
    }
    return u;
  });
}

void Downloader::go() {
  for(const auto &uri : uris) {
    std::cout << "*******************************" << '\n'
              << "Resolving " << uri.host() << '\n'
              << "*******************************\n\n";

    resolv.async_resolve(
        tcp::resolver::query{uri.host().to_string(), (uri.scheme().to_string() == "https" ? "443" : "80")},
        std::bind(&Downloader::resolve_handler, this, _1, _2, uri));
  }

  ioservice.run();
}

void Downloader::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                              std::shared_ptr<beast::http::response<beast::http::string_body>> response,
                              std::shared_ptr<beast::streambuf>) {
  if(ec) {
    ioservice.post([=] {
      std::cerr << "Problem reading the response: \n"
                << "error : " << ec << '\n'
                << "error_core.value() : " << ec.value() << '\n'
                << "error_core.message() : " << ec.message() << '\n';
    });
    return;
  }

  std::cout << "\n*******************************" << '\n'
            << "Headers\n\n";
  for(auto i : response->fields) std::cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << '\n';
  std::cout << "*******************************"
            << "\n\n";

  std::cout << "Received status code: " << response->status << '\n';

  if((response->status == 301 || response->status == 302) && response->fields.exists("Location")) {
    network::uri u(response->fields["Location"].to_string());
    std::cout << "Added a new request for redirection to " << u.string() << '\n';
    resolv.async_resolve(
        tcp::resolver::query{u.host().to_string(), (u.scheme().to_string() == "https" ? "443" : "80")},
        std::bind(&Downloader::resolve_handler, this, _1, _2, u));
    return;
  }

  std::cout << "*******************************" << '\n'
            << "Response body\n\n" << response->body
            << "\n\n";
}

void Downloader::connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, const network::uri& uri) {
  if(ec) {
    ioservice.post([=] {
      std::cout << "error connecting : " << ec << '\n'
                << "error_core.value() : " << ec.value() << '\n'
                << "error_core.message() : " << ec.message() << '\n';
    });
    return;
  }

  // Send HTTP(S) request using beast
  beast::http::request<beast::http::empty_body> req;
  req.method = "GET";
  req.url = (uri.path().empty() ? "/" : uri.path().to_string());
  req.version = 11;
  req.fields.insert("Host", uri.host().to_string());
  req.fields.insert("User-Agent", "Beast");
  beast::http::prepare(req);

  const bool HTTPS = (uri.scheme().to_string() == "https");
  std::cout << "*******************************" << '\n'
            << "Sending a HTTP" << (HTTPS ? "S" : "") << " request\n\n" << req
            << "*******************************" << '\n';

  beast::http::async_write(tcp_socket, std::move(req), std::bind(&Downloader::queue_read, this, _1));
}

void Downloader::queue_read(const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
  if(ec) {
    ioservice.post([=] {
      std::cerr << "error : " << ec << '\n'
                << "error_core.value() : " << ec.value() << '\n'
                << "error_core.message() : " << ec.message() << '\n';
    });
    return;
  }

  auto response = std::make_shared<beast::http::response<beast::http::string_body>>();
  auto response_streambuf = std::make_shared<beast::streambuf>();

  beast::http::async_read(tcp_socket,
                          *response_streambuf,
                          *response,
                          std::bind(&Downloader::read_handler, this, _1, response, response_streambuf));
}

void Downloader::resolve_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                                 tcp::resolver::iterator it,
                                 const network::uri& uri) {
  if(ec) {
    ioservice.post([=] {
      std::cerr << "Problem resolving URL: \"" << uri.host() << "\"\n" << ec.message() << '\n';
    });
    return;
  }

  auto ep = it->endpoint();
  std::cout << "*******************************" << '\n'
            << "Resolved to " << ep.address() << ':' << ep.port() << '\n'
            << "*******************************"
            << "\n\n";

  tcp_socket.async_connect(*it, std::bind(&Downloader::connect_handler, this, _1, uri));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Missing Headers**

Before going any further, the current code is missing a few headers that it needs, namely: `<functional>` and `<memory>`.

**Navigating to `Location` doesn't work**

Next, I've ran the code against a site that redirects me to a different location and the second call resulted in an error:

`error_core.message()`: A connect request was made on an already connected socket

**HTTPS doesn't currently work**

Using beast for HTTPS requires a bit more code, as can be seen in the [official example](https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast/blob/master/examples/ssl/http_ssl_example.cpp).

**API**

Your `Downloader` class is difficult to use

- It creates its own `io_service` while the user might want to use an already existing one
- It only prints the output using `cout`

C++ provides `std::future<>` to ease working with asynchronous APIs. Futures can also pass exceptions.

I would refactor the code like the following, with the main changes being:

- Pass an already existing `io_service`
- Once created, be able to pass in requests at any time
- Return futures of the beast response class for each individual download. Pass any exception to the future and leave it to the user to handle the result

Suggestion:

> Warning! The code assumes that the `HttpDownloader` instance will not be destroyed while any async operation it initiated is pending. Correctly dealing with cancellation and the lifetime of the downloader instance requires extra code.

```
#include <network/uri/uri.hpp>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

#include <beast/core/streambuf.hpp>
#include <beast/http/string_body.hpp>
#include <beast/http/empty_body.hpp>
#include <beast/http/read.hpp>
#include <beast/http/write.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <future>

class HttpDownloader
{
public:
    using response_type = beast::http::response<beast::http::string_body>;
    using future_type = std::future<response_type>;

    HttpDownloader(boost::asio::io_service& service);
    future_type download_async(const std::string& url);

private:

    struct State
    {
        std::promise<response_type> promise;
        network::uri uri;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&>> ssl_stream;
        std::unique_ptr<beast::http::response<beast::http::string_body>> response;
        std::unique_ptr<beast::streambuf> streambuf;

        State(std::promise<response_type>&& promise, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&& socket) : 
            promise{std::move(promise)}, socket(std::move(socket))
        {
        }
    };
    using state_ptr = std::shared_ptr<State>;

    void download_async(const std::string& url, std::promise<response_type>&& promise);
    void download_async(state_ptr state);
    void on_resolve(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator);
    void on_connect(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec);
    void on_request_sent(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec);
    void on_read(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec);

    boost::asio::io_service& service_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
};

HttpDownloader::HttpDownloader(boost::asio::io_service& service) : service_{ service }, resolver_{ service }
{    
}

HttpDownloader::future_type HttpDownloader::download_async(const std::string& url)
{
    std::promise<response_type> promise;
    auto result = promise.get_future();

    download_async(url, std::move(promise));

    return result;
}

void HttpDownloader::download_async(const std::string& url, std::promise<response_type>&& promise)
{
    auto state = std::make_shared<State>(std::move(promise), boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket{ service_ });
    try
    {
        state->uri = network::uri{ url };

        download_async(state);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        state->promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
    }   
}

void HttpDownloader::download_async(state_ptr state)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(state->uri.host().to_string(), state->uri.scheme().to_string());
    resolver_.async_resolve(query, std::bind(&HttpDownloader::on_resolve, this, state, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}

void HttpDownloader::on_resolve(state_ptr state,
                                const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        state->promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
        return;
    }

    state->socket.async_connect(*iterator, std::bind(&HttpDownloader::on_connect, this, state, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void HttpDownloader::on_connect(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        state->promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
        return;
    }

    beast::http::request<beast::http::empty_body> req;
    req.method = "GET";
    req.url = state->uri.path().empty() ? "/" : state->uri.path().to_string();
    req.version = 11;
    req.fields.insert("Host", state->uri.host().to_string());
    req.fields.insert("User-Agent", "Beast");
    beast::http::prepare(req);

    if (state->uri.scheme().to_string() == "https")
    {
        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx{ boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12 };
        state->ssl_stream = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&>>(state->socket, ctx);
        state->ssl_stream->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
        try
        {
            state->ssl_stream->handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            state->promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            return;
        }

        beast::http::async_write(*state->ssl_stream, std::move(req), 
                                 std::bind(&HttpDownloader::on_request_sent, this, state, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    else
    {
        beast::http::async_write(state->socket, std::move(req), 
                                 std::bind(&HttpDownloader::on_request_sent, this, state, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

}

void HttpDownloader::on_request_sent(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        state->promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
        return;
    }

    state->response = std::make_unique<beast::http::response<beast::http::string_body>>();
    state->streambuf = std::make_unique<beast::streambuf>();

    if (state->ssl_stream)
    {
        beast::http::async_read(*state->ssl_stream, *state->streambuf, *state->response,
                                std::bind(&HttpDownloader::on_read, this, state, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    else
    {
        beast::http::async_read(state->socket, *state->streambuf, *state->response,
                                std::bind(&HttpDownloader::on_read, this, state, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
}

void HttpDownloader::on_read(state_ptr state, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        state->promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(boost::system::system_error(ec)));
        return;
    }

    if ((state->response->status == 301 || state->response->status == 302) && state->response->fields.exists("Location")) 
    {
        download_async(state->response->fields["Location"].to_string(), std::move(state->promise));
        return;
    }

    state->promise.set_value(std::move(*state->response));
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    HttpDownloader downloader{io_service};

    std::string urls[] =
    {
        "http://site1",
        "https://site2"
    };
    std::tuple<std::string, HttpDownloader::future_type> downloads[std::extent<decltype(urls)>::value];

    std::transform(begin(urls), end(urls), begin(downloads), [&](auto& url)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(url, std::move(downloader.download_async(url)));
    });

    std::thread asio_thread{ [&]() { io_service.run();} };

    for (auto& tuple : downloads)
    {
        auto& url = std::get<0>(tuple);
        auto& download = std::get<1>(tuple);

        std::cout << url << "\n===\n";
        try
        {
            auto response = download.get();

            std::cout << "Received status code: " << response.status << '\n';

            for (auto pair : response.fields)
            {
                std::cout << pair.first << " : " << pair.second << '\n';
            }
        }
        catch (boost::system::system_error& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Error (" << e.code() << "): " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    asio_thread.join();
}
```